# Rotating geojson feature with Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, proj4js

I have a GeoJson feature that is rendered with leaflet and proj4(ESPG:31467). Now I want to rotate that feature so that it NW corner points to NE, e.g. 90 deg rotation. Is there a way to do this? Or can you give me hints how to address this issue and develop a LL plugin for such functionality.

Comment: I could imagine that this is doable with [Turf.js](http://turfjs.org/), but I am not sure. You might want to have a look at it.

Comment: Do you know how to rotate coordinates mathematically using a matrix of sines and cosines?

Comment: This is probably what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35445682/895

Answer (score 1):

For points you can do it using CSS, in the layer you can use the pointToLayer function and return a DivIcon with the CSS class you want. Then the CSS has the rotation applied. See http://davetimmins.com/2015/10/07/Rotated-icons-with-leaflet/ for more details.