# Converting Leaflet polygon to GeoJSON?

Tags: polygon, leaflet, geojson, geometry, typescript

I have the following piece of code of my Leaflet application (Typescript):

```
getPolygonMarker(): GeoJSON {
    let itemShape: any = [
        wktToGeoJSON(item['contour'],)
    ];

    const p = new Polygon(itemShape[0].coordinates);
    const latLngs = p.getLatLngs();
    const center = p.getBounds().getCenter();
    const angle = item['heading']);

    const rotatedPoints: Array<LatLng> = [];
    (latLngs[0] as Array<LatLng>).forEach((latLng) => {
        rotatedPoints.push(GeometryUtil.rotatePoint(map, latLng , angle, center));
    });

    p.setLatLngs(rotatedPoints);

    return geoJSON(p);
}

...

map.addLayer(getPolygonMarker())
```

As you can see I first generate a GeoJSON starting from a wkt object and then I convert it to Polygon to be able to use [GeometryUtil plugin](https://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.GeometryUtil/global.html#rotatePoint) `rotatePoint` method.

But I can't figure out how to convert back Polygon to GeoJSON to use it on my map. Using `geoJSON(p)` doesn't do the trick.

I also tried to return Polygon instead of GeoJSON in my `getPolygonMarker()` method and then add it to the map with `addLayer`, but despite I don't get any error there is no shape on my map.

Any solution or workaround?

I have already tried [this solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245583/rotate-point-markers-geojson-leaflet) but it doesn't work. I have also found [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/199249/rotating-geojson-feature-with-leaflet), but I have not tried it because I would not rotate polygon using CSS!

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#polygon-togeojson

Comment: I had tried that, but when I write `return p.toGeoJSON()` I get and error in my IDE: `TS2740: Type Feature<Polygon | MultiPolygon, any> is missing the following properties from type GeoJSON<any, Geometry>: addData, resetStyle, setStyle, options, and 53 more.`

Comment: Ah, typescript transpiling phase. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77875172/how-to-parse-geojson-in-typescript-with-the-geojson-module-and-the-types-geojso and similar.